# Alternative to new_to_publish Hook for Custom Statuses

Tags: hooks, wp-insert-post, post-status

I am looking for the right hook to use for sending out an email notice when a post is inserted. However, I am using custom statuses (in this case 'holding') which doesn't seem to get hit with the new_to_holding hook, so was hoping someone knew of an alternative that gets fired when a post is inserted or perhaps a reason why that hook isn't working right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new_to_holding doesn't exist as a post status transition - you need to use the generic transition_post_status action. Something like (untested):

```
add_action('transition_post_status','my_holding_function', 10, 3);

        function my_holding_function( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
            if ( 'holding' == $new_status ) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't get a result with the above but I am still playing with _transition_post_status

Comment: Oh this did work, I was doing it wrong :)